# How apply tilt effect on dynamically created image control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have XAML code for Image control look like this:

```
Image x:Name="test" local:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="95,300,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Source="/Assets/20121215_082027.jpg"/>
```

Now how can i write this code in csharp.I have dynamically created image control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to work with animation storyboard. This is a similar post about Tilt Effect for Windows 8.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/9a348a15-7f8d-46a9-a26c-4407180ed928/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
TiltEffect.SetIsTiltEnabled(*yourUIobject*, true);
```